# How to pass through a query string parameter with square brackets in Amazon API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to use API Gateway as a caching proxy for an HTTP server, which in turn uses [jsonapi-resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) to define the API.

The issue is that jsonapi-resources requires query string parameters of the form `?page[number]=10&page[size]=10` to paginate results. However, if I try to add `page[number]` to `URL Query String Parameters` on a `Method Request` page, I receive the following error:

[image]

I've also tried to [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the name as `page%5Bnumber%5D` without any success; the parameter is still filtered out.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: did you try to replace `[` by `%5B` and `]` by `%5D`

Comment: I did, @FrédéricHenri.

Answer (score 0):

If you encode the [ by %5B, API Gateway doesn't allow % in the parameter name.

Currently, AWS API Gateway only supports the parameter name matches ^[a-zA-Z0-9._$-]+$

Does page.number work for you?